# Converting base 10 to 12, having trouble adding alphabet characters recursivly

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm having trouble using recursion to add letters to a base 10 - base 12 conversion. How would I go about adding letters into my function? I was thinking about adding an if statement in, but i have no idea where and how to go about this. pointers are appreciated Thanks!

Given a count from 1 to 12:

```
Dec 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 

Duo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 X  E  10
```

my function:

```
template<class myType>
myType convertDec(myType number){
    if(number == 0)
        return number;
    //if statement somewhere in here? not sure considering i can't touch the return statement
    return (number % 12) + 10*convertDec(number / 12);
}
```

example ideal output:

65280 = 31940 **(works fine)**

2147483626 = 4EE23088X **(doesnt work!)**

Comment: `65280` "works" by coincidence: only numbers that end in zero have a chance to work. Try `65281` to see a problem. Also, multiplication by ten is very suspicious.

Comment: You are aware that the return type of `convertDec` doesn't make any sense? The base is merely a representation, thereby you should return something that can represent something. Since you want to present something in a human-readable form a string could be handy. C++ won't magically summon letters into the mystic land of numbers.

Comment: *C++ won't magically summon letters into the mystic land of numbers* Hard, but true statement. And why would one solve this with recursion? Recursion is best used in scenarios where a problem can be devided and conquered easily.

Comment: @zeta thanks for the input, How would i go about writing this recursively then? Would i return a string, then convert it for integer operations?

Comment: Please answer why you want recursion here. This is definitly no out-of-shelf use-case for recursion

Comment: @MareInfinitus I'm learning recursion at the moment?

Comment: Okay, you found a good point to distinguish when to use recursion and when not to use it. But that is just my opinion. Recursion has downsides, maximum stack size is just one of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string ConvertToDuodecimal(unsigned long long n)
{
  if (n < 12)
    return string() + "0123456789XE"[n];
  return ConvertToDuodecimal(n / 12) + ConvertToDuodecimal(n % 12);
}

int main()
{
  cout << ConvertToDuodecimal(0) << endl;
  cout << ConvertToDuodecimal(1) << endl;
  cout << ConvertToDuodecimal(10) << endl;
  cout << ConvertToDuodecimal(11) << endl;
  cout << ConvertToDuodecimal(12) << endl;
  cout << ConvertToDuodecimal(13) << endl;
  cout << ConvertToDuodecimal(65280) << endl;
  cout << ConvertToDuodecimal(2147483626) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/YXTBgY)):

```
0
1
X
E
10
11
31940
4EE23088X
```

Comment: I think string("0123456789XE"[n], 1) would probably compile to more efficient code for the base case. Single construction vs construction, conversion and concatenation.

Comment: @PeteFordham Other optimizations are also possible. It's just a very straightforward implementation, where it can be seen what's going on.

Comment: @MareInfinitus Pretty standard.

Comment: wow, this is actually a really cool solution! thanks for much, that array trick is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The base is a property of the way a number is displayed and nothing to do with it's internal representation. You need to write a function that prints a normal int using base 12.

```
a = 12;         // A = 12 (in base 10)
printf("%d",a); // Prints a in base 10 (still 12)
printf("%x",a); // Prints a in base 16 (now C)
```

You code is changing the actual value, which isn't the right thing to do.

(and yes, before the pedants strike, printf isn't good C++...)